# Bresser Water Leakage sensor checksum algorithm

Tags: crc, checksum

I am trying to decode the Bresser Water Leakage sensor, the current state of work can be found in https://github.com/matthias-bs/rtl_433/blob/master/src/devices/bresser_leakage.c

I have also created an [issue](https://github.com/merbanan/rtl_433/issues/2576) with some background information for integrating the decoder in the rtl_433 project.

Decoding the payload works fine, but I did not find out how the checksum is calculated. The data layout and samples are provided in [bresser_leakage.c](https://github.com/matthias-bs/rtl_433/blob/master/src/devices/bresser_leakage.c).

I have already tried the following:

1. Digest calculations used in [rtl_433](https://github.com/merbanan/rtl_433) decoders for other Bresser sensors

- with varying payload lengths)
- with iterating the key in the range 0...0xFFFF

4. [revdgst](https://github.com/triq-org/revdgst) (with varying payload lengths)
5. [reveng](https://sourceforge.net/projects/reveng/) (with varying payload lengths) - no meaningful result at all
6. CRC calculators on https://crccalc.com/
7. Simple checksum algorithms like ADD, XOR, SUB

- on bytes
- on nibbles
- on 16-bit chunks

8. Parity

- bits set - byte wise/nibble wise, first/second half of message, ...

None of these attempts were successful.

I would be happy if anyone could help.

Thank you very much in advance!

Matthias

Answer (score 1):

The checksum has been found!
It's a CRC16/xmodem covering the 5 bytes following the CRC.

See https://github.com/merbanan/rtl_433/issues/2576#issuecomment-1751134478